# Using NInject to find a class, but constructing the class with your own parameters

Tags: ninject

I know this is not good practice.

Here is some code that sort of demonstrates the problem (but doesn't actually work):

```
public interface IBar {}

public interface Bar : IBar {}

public interface IFoo {}

public class Foo : IFoo
{
    public Foo(IBar bar)
    {
    }
}

public class InjectionModule : NinjectModule
{
    public override void Load()
    {
        Bind<IFoo>().To<Foo>();
    }
}

public class MyApp
{
      public void DoSomething()
      {
          // Get a foo with a particular bar
          var foo1 = Kernel.Get<IFoo>(new Bar());

          // Get another foo with a different bar
          var foo2 = Kernel.Get<IFoo>(new Bar());
      }
}
```

So what I am trying to do is to use NInject to bind IFoo to Foo, but have my app supply the Bar argument to the constructor at runtime, rather than the usual practice where NInject resolves the IBar dependency.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
var foo1 = Kernel.Get<IFoo>(new ConstructorArgument("bar", new Bar()));
```